# Wifi option is missing in status bar

Tags: wireless, taskbar

The wifi option in the status bar is missing, although there is an internet connection.

How can I get the wifi status bar option to show up?

---

[image]

In the picture, you can see that there is no option in the status bar. I had tried the commands but those are not all working. Please tell me how to resolve it.

Comment: Care to add to your question what Ubuntu release and desktop are you using?

Comment: Please post the results (if any) of running this command: `killall nm-applet; nohup nm-applet &`

Comment: Try installing network manager using `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome` ,  `sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen to me before. Turns out it was a simple fix.

First check if `"Indicator Application"` is enabled in startup applications and if not then enable it. you can find startup applications by searching for it in the unity dash.

Next you'll want to install the following two packages: `indicator-applet` and `indicator-network` by typing the following command into a new terminal window.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-network
```

you should now have the wifi icon back.